# Emacs is slow and lags when open link

Tags: performance, emacs

My emacs is sometimes slow. Especially when I open link under cursor.

I have run profiler. What next to do with it? How to improve performance?

Results is as below.
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

```
- command-execute                                                 113  52%
 - call-interactively                                             113  52%
  - evil-ex                                                        30  13%
   - read-from-minibuffer                                          23  10%
    + command-execute                                               6   2%
    + elscreen-run-screen-update-hook                               2   0%
      redisplay_internal (C function)                               1   0%
  - eval-expression                                                28  12%
   - eval                                                          28  12%
    - debug                                                        28  12%
     - recursive-edit                                              24  11%
      - command-execute                                            16   7%
       - call-interactively                                        16   7%
        + evil-ex                                                   7   3%
        + byte-code                                                 4   1%
        + evil-mouse-drag-region                                    3   1%
        + org-open-at-point                                         1   0%
        + mouse-set-point                                           1   0%
  - evil-mouse-drag-region                                         14   6%
   - evil-mouse-drag-track                                         14   6%
    - eval                                                         14   6%
     - track-mouse                                                 14   6%
      - byte-code                                                  14   6%
       - read-event                                                 9   4%
        + redisplay_internal (C function)                           1   0%
  - org-agenda                                                     10   4%
   - byte-code                                                     10   4%
    - org-agenda-get-restriction-and-command                       10   4%
     - byte-code                                                   10   4%
        read-char-exclusive                                         8   3%
  - byte-code                                                       9   4%
   - read-file-name                                                 9   4%
    + read-file-name-default                                        9   4%
  + minibuffer-complete                                             5   2%
  + org-open-at-point                                               4   1%
  + org-todo                                                        4   1%
  + org-refile                                                      3   1%
  + evil-previous-line                                              2   0%
  + profiler-report-write-profile                                   2   0%
  + profiler-report                                                 1   0%
  + org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c                                               1   0%
- timer-event-handler                                              62  28%
 - byte-code                                                       62  28%
  - apply                                                          62  28%
   - tooltip-timeout                                               62  28%
    - run-hook-with-args-until-success                             62  28%
     - tooltip-help-tips                                           62  28%
      - tooltip-show                                               62  28%
       - byte-code                                                 62  28%
        - x-show-tip                                               59  27%
         - face-set-after-frame-default                            59  27%
          - byte-code                                              59  27%
           - face-spec-recalc                                      57  26%
            - make-face-x-resource-internal                        54  24%
             - set-face-attributes-from-resources                  53  24%
              - set-face-attribute-from-resource                   50  23%
               + face-name                                          4   1%
            + face-spec-set-2                                       2   0%
- ...                                                              26  11%
   Automatic GC                                                    25  11%
 + vc-backend                                                       1   0%
+ elscreen-run-screen-update-hook                                   5   2%
  mouse-fixup-help-message                                          4   1%
+ redisplay_internal (C function)                                   4   1%
  and                                                               2   0%
+ tooltip-show-help                                                 1   0%
```

### Update 1

For some time no longer I observe this problem.

Comment: Nothing in the profile report looks especially problematic.  Are you opening links in an external application that needs to be fired up in order to display the link -- e.g., a web browser or a PDF viewer?  Some more details about what type of link you have created and how you expect it to work would be helpful.

Comment: @lawlist Sample of link [[file:i:/path/someFile.org][somefile todo something]]. I'm opening it in emacs with C-c C-o as new window/frame. The problem is that normally opens immediately, but when the problem occurs, that lasts for a few seconds.